# Getting a NullPointerException when trying to create ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm working on an arraylist that will add random tiles to a bag for a scrabble game. My teacher has done a horrible job of explaining things so I'm having to work through this all. I've created constructors for the bag and am attempting to create the bag but am getting a null pointer exception when calling.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at h2.RandBag.add(RandBag.java:11)

Heres the code in main returning the error:

```
    for (Integer ival : rbag)
      System.out.println(ival);
```

And heres the methods I'm using for constructing.

```
private ArrayList<E> bag; // container
private Random rand;      // random generator

//constructors
public RandomBag(){
  this.bag = new ArrayList<E>();
  this.rand = new Random();

public RandomBag(int seed) {
  this.bag = new ArrayList<E>();
  this.rand = new Random(seed);
```

And the iterator since it returns null and that could be the problem.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

    return null;
}
```

I've tried returning different things but get an error each time. Iterators haven't been explained all that much so I might be missing something.

```
RandomBag<Integer> rbag = new RandomBag<Integer>(17);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
rbag.add(10+i);
```

Comment: Where is rbag declared and initialized?

Comment: Sorry added in the code for initializing.

Answer (score 9):

#### A better `iterator()` implementation

Although, I don't know all of your requirements and your current implementation, I'm pretty sure that this here's a better implementation:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return bag.iterator();
}
```

#### Explanation of the foreach loop

Note that this:

```
for (Integer ival : rbag)
    System.out.println(ival);
```

... is just syntax sugar for this:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = rbag.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
```

This will then explain the `NullPointerException`

#### Best Practice

Note that if you don't want to completely implement an interface like `List`, instead of simply returning null, you should better throw an exception:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

It will then be much clearer why things don't work (yet)

Comment: for throwing an exception rather than returning a null+1

Answer (score 4):

Yup, the `iterator()` returning `null` is the problem.

That `for` loop is basically sugar for:

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = rbag.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Integer ival = iter.next();
    System.out.println(ival);
}
```

If `iterator()` returns null, then the `iter.hasNext()` invocation will result in the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Writing this:

```
 for (Integer ival : rbag)
      System.out.println(ival);
```

Is the same as writing this:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = rbag.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
   Integer ival = iterator.next();
   System.out.println(ival);
}
```

It's just a syntax sugar. So if you return a null iterator from your collection (rbag) it will allways end in a NullPointerException (java will try to ask that iterator for .hasNext() immediatly after that)

I suggest you do something like

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return this.bag.iterator();
}
```

Comment: Yep that worked. Thanks. I thought null didn't seem right and I actually tried returning this, just didn't have the rest.